# Flutter text left alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to align all the text to left. However, it's in the middle always as you can see the image below. I've tried using `Align` widget and setting `textAlign` property on `Text` widget to `TextAlign.left` but no luck.

[image]

**card.dart**

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
        child: Image.network('https://loremflickr.com/100/100'),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Marry Jane',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Make-up Artist',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff666666)),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                '3.5',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xff666666)),
              ),
              Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.starHalf)
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have you tried giving the Column CrossAxisAlignment.start?

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          elevation: 2,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
            child: Image.network('https://loremflickr.com/100/100'),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
          child: Column(
            /// Add this
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Marry Jane',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Text(
                'Make-up Artist',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff666666)),
              ),
              Text(
                '3.5',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xff666666)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Comment: It worked but I don't understand why its center default. I'm used to Android Layout, just having difficult times sometimes, thanks.

Comment: Also you could clean all the Alignment and textAlign. I have edited the answer